# How to create iOS NFC full-featured application?

Tags: ios, nfc, emv, core-nfc

There is such a question. Apple Core NFC doc says that "Core NFC doesn't support payment-related Application IDs". However, there are persistent rumors about some kind of "Apple tap to pay". It turns out, if you really want to, then you can. It is also known that in production there are quite complex applications like ID passport readers, etc., which, as it were, hints. Are there any considerations by which means it would be possible to implement a full-featured NFC application with all the features like ISO 7816, ISO 14443, APDU exchange, TLV parsing, etc., suitable for contactless payments as well?

Comment: Apps can only make use of Core NFC and the facilities it provides.  Lower level access may be possible with a jailbreak

Comment: The Apple NFC hardware is capable of lots of things, just Apple has been restricting some of the functionality to itself for use in it's wallet and not making it available to the normal developer. Tap to Pay seem to be just adding some features to their wallet and not actually expanding the NFC capabilities available to the normal developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, my main concerns would be around App Review Guidelines, I gave it a quick look, but couldn't fine anything against this, so maybe you can?

Tap to Pay has been officially announced, you can use those API for your own contactless payments, Stripe is doing it, and more providers are coming.

Comment: You will need to work with a payment provider, like Stripe. Stripe is accepting beta program requests. The stripe SDK will handle the nfc